# dynamically changing ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, sendmail, actionmailer

I need some of my emails to go using "smtp" and some others using "sendmail". Is there a clean way to switch between delivery methods depending on the mailer method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define it with his configuration

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

And in other part of your app :

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```